# What characterizes the incidence matrix of a tripartite hypergraph?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matrices, hypergraph

The incidence matrix of a graph $G = (V,E)$ is a matrix with $|V|$ rows and $|E|$ columns, in which element $v,e$ is $1$ if node $v$ is incident to edge $e$, and $0$ otherwise.

In bipartite graphs, the incidence matrix has the following property (called "total unimodularity"): the determinant of every square submatrix is either $-1$ or $0$ or $1$. This property is very useful, because it implies that every linear program in which the constraints are based on this matrix (for example: for finding a maximum cardinality matching, maximum weight matching or minimum vertex cover) has a solution in which all values are integers.

I am now researching **tripartite hypergraphs**. Their incidence matrix need not be totally unimodular. For example, consider the hypergraph on the vertices $\{1,4,2,5,3,6\}$ with hyperedges: $\{ \{4,5,3\}, \{4,2,6\}, \{1,5,6\} \}$. Its incidence matrix is 6 by 3:

\begin{pmatrix}0& 0& 1\\0 &1 &0\\1& 0& 0\\1& 1& 0\\1& 0& 1\\0& 1& 1\end{pmatrix}

The bottom submatrix is a 3-by-3 square matrix whose determinant is $-2$.

Is there another property, weaker than total unimodularity, which characterizes the incidence matrices of tripartite hypergraphs?

<sub>Cross-posted from [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3761729/29780)</sub>

Comment: I believe this is more commonly referred to as an "incidence matrix", not that it matters hugely.